# How do I format Year-Month data with row = 'year' and columns = 'months'

Tags: python, dataframe, date, time-series

I'm working with a data set from a url, which I've messily formatted to the following:

```
url = r"https://psl.noaa.gov/enso/mei/data/meiv2.data"
r = requests.post(url) #read url
s = r.text #url data to string
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=',', header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL) #make pd dataframe
df2 = df.drop(index=[0, 46, 47, 48, 49]) #drop the unnessicary data
df3 = df2[0].str.split('\s+', expand = True) #reformat to new df
df3.columns = ['Year', 'DJ', 'JF', 'FM', 'MA', 'AM', 'MJ', 'JJ', 'JA', 'AS', 'SO', 'ON', 'ND'] #name the columns
```

Printing df3 results in the dataframe:
[that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTXrB.png)

This is fine to look at, but I want to create a time-series plot of MEI from 1979-2023 including each month. That is to say, the X-axis from Dec-Jan 1979 thru Nov-Dec 2023 with MEI values on the Y-axis.

So far, I've tried transposing the dataframe, but ran into the same issues when formatting a plot.

Comment: Which column has the data for each month: Dec-Jan, Jan-Feb,...? What kind of time-series plot are you looking for - line? bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do, to simplify your code, is point out that [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is capable of doing a bunch of the transformations you're doing, just by specifying options. For example, you can split fields by whitespace by including `delim_whitespace=True`.

```py
import pandas as pd

months = ['DJ', 'JF', 'FM', 'MA', 'AM', 'MJ', 'JJ', 'JA', 'AS', 'SO', 'ON', 'ND']

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://psl.noaa.gov/enso/mei/data/meiv2.data",
    delim_whitespace=True,
    names=['Year', *months],
    skiprows=1,
    skipfooter=4,
    na_values=[-999],
    engine='python'
)
```

The next step is to "unpivot" the data. I use a function called [`DataFrame.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to do this. By setting `value_vars=months`, I am telling it that each value in each row and column should become a new row, labeled by what row (year) and what column (month) it was in.

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Year'], var_name='month', value_vars=months)
```

This gives us a dataframe with year, seasonal code, and value:

```
   Year month  value
0  1979    DJ   0.47
1  1980    DJ   0.35
2  1981    DJ  -0.33
```

Next, I map this month code into an integer to represent the month of the year. I turn `DJ` into 1, `JF` into 2, and so on. This step is a little scientifically iffy - it sounds like this data represents a span of time, and those spans of time overlap. You should ask someone who understands the dataset if what I'm doing here makes sense.

```py
df['month'] = df['month'].map({m: i + 1 for i, m in enumerate(months)})
```

Next, I take the year column and month column and combine it into a single date column. This allows me to use Pandas to plot the data as a time-series.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].map(str) + '-' + df['month'].map(str))
```

This next step is purely aesthetic: I find it nicer to work with sorted dataframes.

```py
df = df.sort_values('date')
```

Finally, after preparing the data in the correct format, you can make a plot with:

```py
df.plot(x='date', y='value')
```

Output:

[image: plot of mei data]